# SQLTransaction Multiadd response redirect not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sqltransaction

I am using transaction to add diffrent database tables. When ı add `Response.redirect("");` I am getting the error : `SQLTransaction complete; is no longer available.` If ı delete the response.redirect, It is working fine without the error.

```
protected void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection baglanti = system.baglan();
            SqlCommand Trans_isl1 = new SqlCommand("Insert TblDetay (Ad,Yerler,Ulasim,Resim,Durum) values(@Ad,@Yerler,@Ulasim,@Resim,@Durum)", baglanti);

            Trans_isl1.Parameters.Add("@Ad", "deneme");
            Trans_isl1.Parameters.Add("@Yerler", "sdfgjkj");
            Trans_isl1.Parameters.Add("@Ulasim", "ads1");
            Trans_isl1.Parameters.Add("@Resim", "1.jpg");
            Trans_isl1.Parameters.Add("@Durum", true);

            SqlTransaction sqlTrans = baglanti.BeginTransaction(); // Transaction nesnesine işlemleri eşitliyoruz.
            Trans_isl1.Transaction = sqlTrans; 
            try
            {  
                 Trans_isl1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 sqlTrans.Commit();
                 Response.Redirect("second.aspx?id="+ Session["id"]);
            }

            catch (Exception hata)
            { 
                Response.Write("İşleminiz yapılamadı, Oluşan Hatanın Detayı<br />" + hata);
                sqlTrans.Rollback();  
            }

            finally
            {  
                baglanti.Close();
                baglanti.Dispose();
                Trans_isl1.Dispose(); 
            }



        }
```

Comment: You are calling BeginTransaction after executing your first command. Try to Call BeginTransaction before executing first command.

Comment: Also, your `SqlTransaction` need to be in `using` blocks to ensure it is cleaned up.

Comment: Maybe Response.Write Call Response.End somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response.Redirect calls Response.End, which will throw a ThreadAbortException, which is caught by your catch block and then the Rollback cannot occur because the transaction has already been committed. You can use Server.Transfer instead or use overload of Response.Redirect that allows you to specify whether Response.End is called.

See this link for more info 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629

Comment: Thank you its worked in my code `Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);`